# MongoDB slow aggregate with $sort after $lookup

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am having some slow aggregate query that uses `$lookup` and `$sort`.

Assume a `users` collection with fields:

```
_id - UUID
createdAt - Date
...
...
```

The following query takes **~5 seconds**

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
    {$lookup: {from: 'orders', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'user', as: 'orders'}},
    {$addFields: {orders: {$size: '$orders'}}},
    {$sort: {createdAt: -1}},
    {$skip: 0},
    {$limit: 20}
])
```

When removing the `$sort` stage it takes **0.2 seconds**

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
    {$lookup: {from: 'orders', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'user', as: 'orders'}},
    {$addFields: {orders: {$size: '$orders'}}},
    {$skip: 0},
    {$limit: 20}
])
```

I do have an index on the `createdAt` field.

Does having `$lookup` prevent the usage of the index?
Thx.

Comment: This might not answer the question, but I would store the number of orders in the user document. You wouldn't have to do any lookup/projection in that case.

Comment: Yes, I know I can better arrange the schema to match the reports, but currently all the reports are just temporary so I dont want to change the schema based on it. This is more of an "educational" question. thx